# No coins received from Kucoin to Metamask transfer

Tags: metamask, withdrawal

This is the hash number:
0xc9a55ff01e26ccbd5f0484d351c61735e0088ba025b54f98f08d6bc944fd6ec0

I transfered from kucoin to metamask, transaction states successful, but I don't see my coins on metamask.

Comment: Which chain's hash is this, I didn't find this hash record.